# Abrir um Script e fechar outro

Tags: javascript

Olá! Achei um script de slide, e ele dá suporte pra passar as imagens em vertical e horizontal. No caso eu coloquei 2 botões pro usuário escolher e fazer a troca... quando eu clico em vertical ou horizontal ele funciona normal, mas quando um dos dois está selecionado e mudo pra outro, fica os 2 rodando. Como faço pra quando clicar em um o outro parar de rodar?

O site do slide: http://idangero.us/swiper/

```
<li><a href="#!" id="horizontal">Horizontal</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!" id="vertical">Vertical</a></li>
```

---

```
$("#vertical").click(function(){
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      direction: 'vertical',
      zoom: true,
      scrollbar: {
        el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        hide: true,
      },
      });
    });
    $("#horizontal").click(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
          zoom: true,
          scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
            hide: true,
          },
          });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve usar o método `destroy` (**[doc do plugin](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#methods)**) do plugin para removê-lo do DOM e em seguida criá-lo novamente com a direção desejada.

> Não use `var` dentro das funções para criar a instância do plugin,
>   caso contrário ele ficará inacessível na outra função.

```
$("#vertical").click(function(){
   swiper.destroy();
   swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      direction: 'vertical',
      scrollbar: {
         el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
         hide: true,
      }
   });
 });

$("#horizontal").click(function(){
   swiper.destroy();
   swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      scrollbar: {
         el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
         hide: true,
      }
   });
});
```

#### Outra opção de código

Você pode criar uma função para isso, para não repetir o código, pegando a direção pelo `id` do botão clicado:

```
function destroiSwiper(dir){
   swiper.destroy();
   swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      zoom: true,
      direction: dir,
      scrollbar: {
         el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
         hide: true,
      }
   });
}

$("#vertical, #horizontal").click(function(e){
   destroiSwiper( e.target.id );
});
```

Comment: Olha, funcionou! Mt obrigado!